# how to add arguments to a Qt PySide built-in Signal when connecting to a Slot

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qlineedit

This is the class where I'm trying to implement a simple expression evaluator:

```
class mainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, mainGui.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(*args, **kwargs)
        super(mainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connecting_range_displays()

    def connecting_range_displays(self):    
        ranges = num_ranges()
        first_range = num_ranges.ones_range
        second_range = num_ranges.tens_range

        print first_range
        print second_range

        self.top_lineEdit.setText(str(first_range))
        self.bottom_lineEdit.setText(str(second_range))

        ex_a = first_range + second_range
        print "this is expressions answer", ex_a

        self.answer_lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(self.ex_evaluator)

    def ex_evaluator(self, right_answer):
        answer = self.answer_lineEdit.text()

        if ex_a == right_answer:
            print "Correct answer bucko"
```

In the above code for a simple arithmetic practice application I use two lines to display random numbers in a certain range, and the third `QlineEdit` i.e `answer_lineEdit` I use it to get user input and then to check if its correct I use the `Signal` `returnPressed` and connect it to the `ex_evaluator` which will then tell you if you have given a correct response, the problem seems to be that I cannot pass the `ex_a` argument to the function to be able to evaluate it, could it be namespace issue, I'm a pretty new at coding and my philosophy is to only learn the least amount to get me to where I want so I'm wondering if I will have to learn how to subclass the `QLineEdit` which I have no idea how to do, I saw that maybe decorators might help which is another bucket of trouble I don't want to get into.

Comment: You can use QSignalMapper: http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/QSignalMapper.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do one of the following:

- make ex_a a class attribute by changing it to be "self.ex_a". Then it can be used from anywhere within the class
- pass it to the slot (ex_evaluator) using lambda or functools.partial

For the second option, I wrote a tutorial that describes both ways of doing this: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/04/10/pyside-connecting-multiple-widgets-to-the-same-slot/

To use a lambda, do something like this:

```
self.answer_lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(lambda ans=ex_a: self.ex_evaluator(ans))
```

For the functools.partial, it would be something like this:

```
import functools
callback = partial(self.ex_evaluator, ex_a)
self.answer_lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(callback)
```

If you don't understand that last one, you might want to take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial).

Comment: changing the scope by applying self.ex_a worked, will try the other way as well seems I need to start swimming in deeper waters, I bookmarked your blog last night by the way..before posting the question, thanks for the help